# Had to disable Spotlight indexing in Catalina to stop mds_stores using over 100% CPU. Surely there's a better way?

Tags: catalina, spotlight

I have three Macs of various vintages running 10.15.7, all with the latest updates.

My 2019 MBP 16" is the only one that's suffering from mds_stores going nuts and using over 100% CPU.

As a temporary solution I've added all volumes to the Privacy tab, so Spotlight is basically useless, but it seems the only way to stop mds_stores slowing the machine right down and spinning the fans up to maximum.

There has to be a better way that lets me keep Spotlight functionality while not being held hostage to mds_stores, surely?

Comment: How long did you wait for spotlight to finish its indexing?

Comment: In one case, 30 minutes, and it still hadn't finished.

Comment: In any case, why would only one Catalina machine out of three suffer from this? And why the hell should indexing cause the process to take over 100% CPU, ramping the fans up to maximum and slowing everything down on a daily basis?

Comment: What do you mean by daily bases? Spotlight indexes only new files, but if you reinstall a system and transfer a lot of files for example spotlight indexes all these files. 30 minutes is nothing, it can take hours or more. However, usually, once it is done with the first index it will not give you that high CPU usage, since it only searches the new files (like downloads,...)

Comment: I mean, it was happening every day. 30 minutes is utterly unacceptable for a file indexing process, which should be happening invisibly in the background, to be consuming over 100% CPU.

Comment: You are correct that it should not happen everyday, however it needs to finish the process once. Are you transferring a lot of data, do you have many hard drives connected? Also, try to let it finish the process, which does mean it might need a whole day (depending on how much data it has to index - which you still haven't told us)...

Comment: A whole day of 100% CPU and roaring fans just on file indexing, rendering the machine effectively useless for anything else? No, sorry, I'm not buying that. This is clearly a Spotlight bug, especially since so many other people are reporting it.

Comment: Nevertheless, the reality of Spotlight taking a long time to index new files is a well-known phenomenon. Whether it should work like that or not is another issue, but there is no real way to fix it but disable Spotlight. So if you want to use it, you need to let the process finish. What is your situation? How much data are you indexing?

Comment: When I updated my MBP 2015 from Mojave to Catalina it took 2 - 3 **days** to finish indexing. It seems excessive but your best bet is to just let it do its thing without interference and it will finish doing what it needs to, when it is done. No it is not the solution you want and, you are right, it shouldn't take so long (at least from a users standpoint) but you give up an annoyingly hot (and somewhat slower) Mac for a couple of days, for *years* of faithful use.